# Don't embed "standard fonts" in PDF produced by LibreOffice to reduce file size

Tags: pdf, fonts, openoffice, libreoffice

### Before

I have an "old" 2 pages ODT document. The ODT file is about **30 kB**. When I exported the document to PDF with an old OpenOffice 3.2, the resulting file was too big (> **200 kB** I think).

Back then, I found a trick to avoid that: *I selected all text within the file and manually changed the font by typing "Times" in the font selection box*. Even if I didn't have a font named "Times" on my system, it worked pretty well, producing a **~30 kB** PDF file.

Here is the result of `pdffonts oo-file.pdf`:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Times-Bold                           Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      26  0
Times-Roman                          Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      24  0
DAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold               TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     18  0
Times-BoldItalic                     Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      27  0
Times-Italic                         Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      25  0
GAAAAA+DejaVuSerif                   TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     23  0
HAAAAA+OpenSymbol                    TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     13  0
```

As you can see, *the "Times" font is not embedded*, and does not need to be, because it is part of the [standard 14 fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Standard_Type_1_Fonts_.28Standard_14_Fonts.29) that any PDF reader should be able to display.

### Trouble starting

But now, I am using LibreOffice 5.2.3 which apparently [changed it's font embedding policy](http://fuckubuntu.blogspot.fr/2011/06/the-open-office-office-libre-font.html). The very same file, exported to PDF is now **417 kB** big (x14).

Look `pdffonts oo-file-exported-with-lo.pdf`:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
NimbusRomNo9L-Medi                   Type 1            Builtin          yes no  yes     36  0
NimbusRomNo9L-Regu                   Type 1            Builtin          yes no  yes     52  0
NimbusRomNo9L-Regu                   Type 1            Custom           yes no  yes     55  0
EAAAAA+Verdana-Bold                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     18  0
NimbusRomNo9L-Medi                   Type 1            Custom           yes no  yes     39  0
NimbusRomNo9L-MediItal               Type 1            Builtin          yes no  yes     28  0
NimbusRomNo9L-MediItal               Type 1            Custom           yes no  yes     31  0
NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal               Type 1            Builtin          yes no  yes     44  0
JAAAAA+TimesNewRomanPSMT             TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     23  0
NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal               Type 1            Custom           yes no  yes     47  0
LAAAAA+OpenSymbol                    TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     13  0
```

### Workaround

I managed to significantly reduce this file size to **54 kB** by converting it to ps, and back to PDF:

```
pdf2ps lo-file-edited.pdf temp.ps
ps2pdf temp.ps smaller.pdf
```

Which gives (`pdffonts smaller.pdf`):

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
KUEZVI+NimbusRomNo9L-Medi            Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no       8  0
XHHJOA+NimbusRomNo9L-Regu            Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      10  0
LEKIBS+Verdana-Bold                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      12  0
WMOWQS+NimbusRomNo9L-MediItal        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      14  0
SOLBEP+NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      16  0
OJIXHX+TimesNewRomanPSMT             TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      18  0
OJIXHX+OpenSymbol                    TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      20  0
```

However, I think this workaround is not very elegant, and anyway, it still produces a file about twice bigger as the first one.

## Question

So, **how can I force LibreOffice to use the PDF [standard 14 fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Standard_Type_1_Fonts_.28Standard_14_Fonts.29) *without* embedding them in the resulting PDF file?**

I would like a relatively small file.

Free software solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a caveat: Not embedding (and subsetting) fonts is very bad practice.

Comment: @MaxWyss Except if using the "standard 14 fonts", right?

Comment: No exception. There have been no "standard 14 fonts" for more than a decade. In order to display properly, and to be compliant to ISO 32000 (aka PDF), or subgroups (PDF/X, PDF/A), all fonts must be embedded (and subsetted). The "standard 14 fonts" are kind of a leftover of the old style way to create PDF, using PostScript, and then Distiller (which is essentially a PostScript printer). PostScript printers, if using the Adobe engine, do indeed come along with those "standard 14 fonts".

Comment: @MaxWyss "No exception."  Yabut, as you know, when government meets technology, there is an exception.  For example, the Texas courts [disallow embedded fonts in electronically filed PDFs](http://www.txcourts.gov/media/273991/order-13-9165.pdf)

Comment: @PatrickMaupin: If that is indeed true, they have no clue at all, and live on the faith that it never backfires… And they should immediately fire their consultant. (again, if that is really true).

Comment: @MaxWyss -- All I know is what I read in the doc on the txcourts.gov.  Whether they enforce it or not is not something I yet know.

Comment: @MaxWyss can you please mention reference to these statements: "There have been no "standard 14 fonts" for more than a decade. In order to display properly, and to be compliant to ISO 32000 (aka PDF), or subgroups (PDF/X, PDF/A), all fonts must be embedded (and subsetted)."